# Is there an equivalent of virtual env but for the whole of ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, opencv, virtualenv

Python has a wonderful tool called a virtual environment, which lets you effectively hermetically seal various python libraries (which may conflict with each other!) from each other. Is there an equivalent tool for the whole of Ubuntu? Or, rather, for things I `make`?

For instance, I have a repo that requires a modified version of OpenCV 3.0. However, I'd like to `make` *another* version of OpenCV, version 3.1.0, with CUDA support, for an entirely different repo that I'm working on in parallel, as well as obtain the bugfixes in OpenCV 3.1.0. I'm not skilled enough to port the changes from the modified OpenCV 3.0 to OpenCV 3.1.0...is there a way to install both without them fighting? Perhaps with  the Ubuntu equivalent of a virtual env?

Comment: [LXC](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html) and Docker, perhaps?

Comment: Possibly chroot.  It may be a bit heavy-handed, but it seems like it could work, if I understand it correctly.  Unfortunately, I can't really provide any details on how.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot for more info.

Comment: Source different bash files with different $PATHS.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use [vagrant](https://vagrantup.com). 
Using vagrant you can easily create/destroy/re-create development and testing environments.

You use with docker,lxd,virtualbox as [providers](https://vagrantup.com/docs/providers/) to build,test packages without making any change in your host system. It is very helpful to create identical development environments.

Vagrant provides functionality to [take/restore snapshots](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html) of your virtual environment. Using  [docker as vagrant provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html), you can build/test your virtual environment in no time. For example you need to test some new package, you just need to [build docker image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/) once with preinstalled libraries. Vagrant will provision docker image and test/run your built package. This way it saves lots of time to build virtual environment. You can use same image multiple times.

To install Vagrant, [Download latest vagrant linux zip file](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html),unzip it and copy vagrant binary to `/usr/bin`.

```
unzip vagrant*_linux_amd64.zip
sudo cp vagrant /usr/bin/
```

or You can install vagrant via apt.

```
sudo apt install vagrant
```

Verify vaagrant installation.

```
vagrant --version
```

Comment: `sudo apt install vagrant`